# statically link lib file causes link-error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, static-linking

I **statically** link `fw.lib` in my `C++/CLI` project, and get these errors:

`Error  1   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00001B) "extern "C" unsigned int __cdecl func(unsigned int,unsigned char *)" (?func@@$$J0YAIIPAE@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __clrcall Sdk::Native::Method(void)" (?Method@Native@Sdk@@$$FSMXXZ)  C:\project\Sdk.obj  Sdk`

`Error  2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" unsigned int __cdecl func(unsigned int,unsigned char *)" (?func@@$$J0YAIIPAE@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __clrcall Sdk::Native::Method(void)" (?Method@Native@Sdk@@$$FSMXXZ)   C:\project\Sdk.obj  Sdk`

What do I do wrong ? I did this:

- Added the lib path in [project properties -> Library Directories]
- Added `fw.lib` file under [project properties -> Additional Dependencies]
- Wrapped all functions in `fw.h` with `extern "C" {...}`

Any idea ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved...

Apparently when you link, for instance, x64 bit into x32 project (and vice versa ??), the linker produces a **very general** link-error.

FYI :-)